# Revoke individual slack integration tokens

Tags: slack, slack-api

We have a Bot and Incoming Webhook integrations in Slack for our App.

They're user configurable and we'd like a button in our app to remove the slack integration so when they remove it at our end it syncs up with the Slack integrations page too - so you can remove integrations from within our app.

Slack have the `auth.revoke` method but this revokes the whole app rather than just the token/integration on an individual basis.  Is there a way of revoking just a single token for the Bot or an incoming webhook?

Comment: Could you figure out a way to remove a webhook without revoking the whole app? I'm facing a similar situation, currently deleting the hook from our side but it's still allowed (and thus listed) from Slack's side.

Comment: @Gabin Nope, we ended up binning the feature and relying on people to manage it on Slack's side.  Shame really